# Get value out from JSON in Swift xcode 6

Tags: json, swift, xcode6, nsurlsession

I have a JSON file which i converted to a NSDictionary object. My question is how do i get one single value out from this object? I make a httppost to my webside and then i get an JSON array back with to values "success" ,"userId" and "token i want to check on the "access_token" string in "token"

```
public class HttpPost{

var URLstring : String = "http://95.85.53.176/nhi/api/app/login"
var ClientSecret : String = "SqzssXGU0C5ukzgvivVTeg7QdlZcnBUKULECgkFp"

public func HttpPostToLogin(Email: String, Password: String, completionHandler: (responseSuccess: Int32) -> ())
{

    var postString = "email=" + Email + "&password=" + Password + "&client_secret=" + ClientSecret

    //Declare URL
    var url: NSURL! = NSURL(string: URLstring)
    var request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)

    //Declare which HTTPMethod
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    //POST data
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    //new thread for receiving data
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil
        {
            println("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        //Check if there is response from server
        println("response =\(response)")

        var responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)


        println("responseString =\(responseString)")


        var error: NSError?

        //parse JSON file
        var myJSON : NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error: &error) as! NSDictionary

        println(myJSON)

        //this works
        var success = myJSON["success"]!.intValue

        //Tried - gives me an error
        //var accessToken = myJSON["token"]["access_token"]!.stringValue

        //println(accessToken)

        //complete task and return success value
        completionHandler(responseSuccess: success!)



    }


    task.resume()

}
}
```

output:

```
{
success = 1;
token =     {
    "access_token" = p9f9ge3Fe1dn5T7xpfBZHfZaA7CwYe9fbLNgeqOY;
    "expires_in" = 604800;
    "refresh_token" = w0qltq4SDax5KtIKEEFZm76CsB9BfozsuSrGuRcI;
    "token_type" = Bearer;
};
userId = 61;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to cast value as `String`

```
var tokenDict: NSDictionary = myJSON["token"] as! NSDictionary
var accessToken: String = tokenDict["access_token"] as! String
```

For UserID:

```
var myUserID: Int = myJSON["userId"] as! Int
```

Comment: var accessToken = myJSON["userId"]!.stringValue
when i print this out it gives me "nil" ??? - it is exactly the same as the one that works with "success"

Comment: @LocDaiLe I hope, now you can get the rest of the things. If not, then let me know :)

Comment: i don't understand the tokendict declaring? @Sohil R. Memon

Comment: It's a best practice! In order to get dictionary from another dictionary, you should cast as `NSDictionary`. Otherwise, it will automatically cast as `AnyObject`. And also please check that your jsonData is not nil at the time of getting response, otherwise you will get a crash there. @LocDaiLe

Comment: How do i check if token is not nil?I have try to implement the code below but it never go in to the if scope - evne though token is not nil.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85402/discussion-between-sohil-r-memon-and-loc-dai-le).

Answer (score 1):

You should check token is not nil before accessing its value. Otherwise app will crash. Following code will execute when token is not nil and myJSON["token"] is type of NSDictionary.

```
if let tokenDict = myJSON["token"] as? NSDictionary {
    var accessToken : String? = tokenDict["access_token"] as? String
    var expires_in  : Int? = tokenDict["expires_in"] as? Int
}
```

Comment: yes i got that problem - i used ur code but men i call println inside the if scope it doesn't print anything out??? "@Bhupendra Singh